# Why is this dialog being displayed when I start firefox?

Tags: macos, software, firefox

I'm a beginner Mac OS user.

When I open Firefox I receive the dialog below, why doesn't Firefox just start? What is the point of the below dialog?

[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a dialog, this is the result of mounting (opening) the Firefox.dmg (think of it as an archive or drive image). For mac users it's obvious - you should drag the FF icon to the Applications folder shortcut (the blue folder). This will copy the Firefox application in the /Applications/ folder. Then just unmount (eject) the Firefox.dmg archive and start Firefox from Applications (like you start the rest of your applications).

Comment: …and you can delete the Firefox.dmg (drag it to the trash) after that. :)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The file what you downloaded, is an "DMG" archive type (like ISO image).

- When you double click on it, you open it (called mounted it).
- After opening the archive you should install the application - simple way - drag and drop into the destination.
- After the install - eject and usually can trash the dmg archive.